# Python how to merge dictionaries getting from function and loop

Tags: python

I have several requests to Prometheus for different metrics, which I would like to merge into one dictionary.
Aim of the result should be like this: `{'domain': 'domain.com', 'uptime': '100', 'threats_number': '12345'}`

```py
# Uptime
def uptime_percent():
    uptime_data = prom.custom_query(
        query="avg_over_time(host_tracker_uptime_percent{job='donodeexporter'}[10d])"
    )
    for domain_z in uptime_data:
        domain_zone = domain_z['metric']['zone']
        uptime = domain_z['value'][1]
        yield ({"domain": f'{domain_zone}', "uptime": f'{uptime}'})
```

```py
# Cloudflare threats total by zone
def cloudflare_threats():
    cloudflare_threats_total = prom.custom_query(
        query="sum by(zone) (increase(cloudflare_zone_threats_total{job='cloudflare'}[10d]))"
    )
    for domain_z in cloudflare_threats_total:
        domain_zone = domain_z['metric']['zone']
        threats_number = domain_z['value'][1]
        yield ({"domain": f'{domain_zone}', "threats_number": f'{threats_number}'})
```

Answer (score 0):

It mighn't elegant but partially works for me

```py
# Uptime
def uptime_percent():
    uptime_data = prom.custom_query(
        query="avg_over_time(host_tracker_uptime_percent{job='donodeexporter'}[10d])"
    )
    for domain_z in uptime_data:
        domain_zone = domain_z['metric']['zone']
        uptime = domain_z['value'][1]
        yield dict(([("domain", f'{domain_zone}'), ("uptime", f'{uptime}')]))


# Cloudflare threats total by zone
def cloudflare_threats():
    cloudflare_threats_total = prom.custom_query(
        query="sum by(zone) (increase(cloudflare_zone_threats_total{job='cloudflare'}[10d]))"
    )
    for domain_z in cloudflare_threats_total:
        domain_zone = domain_z['metric']['zone']
        threats_number = domain_z['value'][1]
        yield dict(([("domain", f'{domain_zone}'), ("threats", f'{threats_number}')]))


result_uptime = list(uptime_percent())
result_threats = list(cloudflare_threats())
result_dict = {"total_stats": result_uptime + result_threats}
result_json = json.dumps(result_dict)
print(result_json)
```

It's not elegant because I still don't have got desirable JSON. [The new question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347818/normalise-json-with-python) :)