# Normalise JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

Prompt me, please, how to normalize this JSON file using Python?

This question is related to the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344640/python-how-to-merge-dictionaries-getting-from-function-and-loop/74347839#74347839)

The current JSON contains:

```json
{
    "total_stats": [
        {
            "domain": "domain.com",
            "uptime": "100"
        },
        {
            "domain": "domain.com",
            "threats": "345.01111783804436"
        }
    ]
}
```

Desirable

```json
{
    "total_stats": [
        {
            "domain": "domain.com",
            "uptime": "100",
            "threats": "345.01111783804436"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Anything you have tried already..? Other than that you give no details - should all the list elements be simply merged? Or joined on `domain`? Please be specific.

Comment: Excuse me. This questions is related to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344640/python-how-to-merge-dictionaries-getting-from-function-and-loop/74347839#74347839

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *merge* the dictionaries according the `"domain"` key you can use (note: if dictionaries have common keys, the last dictionary value will be used):

```py
dct = {
    "total_stats": [
        {"domain": "domain.com", "uptime": "100"},
        {"domain": "domain.com", "threats": "345.01111783804436"},
    ]
}


out = {}
for d in dct["total_stats"]:
    out.setdefault(d["domain"], {}).update(d)

dct["total_stats"] = list(out.values())
print(dct)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "total_stats": [
        {
            "domain": "domain.com",
            "uptime": "100",
            "threats": "345.01111783804436",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Andrej Kesely, thank you. This code works for me.